# Set Border Visibility Property Using Button Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers

I need a button click trigger that will change the visibility property for a border. The situation is a logon screen with an error message in the border, and when login is clicked the border collapses prior to the logon logic executing (ideally). I am unable to get the UI to update before executing the logic, which is bound to the login button Command property, using EventTriggers routing the MouseLeftButtonUp/Down events.

Comment: Have you tried an UpdateLayout on the containing object (e.g., your Window) to force the layout to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using a method to force the UI to update.

```
void AllowUIToUpdate() 
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render
                                             , new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object parameter)
                                                   {
                                                       frame.Continue = false;
                                                       return null;
                                                   })
                                             , null);

    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```